# Проблема с переработкой одного словаря в другой

Tags: python, словари

Допустим есть англо-латинский словарь,
к примеру:

```
apple - malum, pomum, popula
fruit - baca, bacca, popum
punishment - malum, multa
```

Вопрос заключается в том что мне нужно сделать латинско-английский словарь
В ответе должно получится так

```
malum - apple,punishment  
pomum - apple  
popula - apple  
baca - fruit  
bacca - fruit  
popum - fruit 
multa - punishment
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе собственную попытку решения и укажите с чем именно у вас возникли затруднения. "Мне нужно" - не является вопросом...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм решения:

1. составляете из исходных данных список списков:

   ```
    [['apple', 'malum'], ['apple', 'pomum'], ..., ['punishment', 'multa']]
   ```
2. проходите в цикле по списку из "пункта 1" и составляете необходимый вам словарь, используя второй элемент внутреннего списка как ключ, а первый - как значение.

PS код не буду приводить пока вы не привидете в вопросе собственную попытку решения.

Comment: Дайте маленькую подсказку,ничего в голову не лезет

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, я уже дал две подсказки ;)

Comment: я не понимаю как это осуществить,просто прошу обьяснения;(

Comment: туплю,с кем не бывает

Comment: Не хочу и не буду нарушать правила форума. Покажите в вопросе что уже сделали и что не получается- тогда поговорим о коде ;)

Comment: что за правила," не помогать людям которые не понимают??" :DDD

Comment: Выдержка из правил: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: ясно,бесполезно что либо просить

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, если вы хотите просить в вашем стиле, то вы ошиблись форумом - обращайтесь к фрилансерам. Они за деньги решат любое домашнее задание и не будут задавать "глупых вопросов", как здесь!